# Storyboard won't open in XCode8

Tags: interface-builder, xcode-storyboard, xcode8

I have a storyboard that opens fine in XCode7.3.1 but in XCode 8 will only open source code, it will not open in Interface Builder. Trying to open it in Interface Builder produces the error: The document "Main.Storyboard" could not be opened. Unrecognized file content.

Answer (score 0):

Got a similar problem, although I had a never ending spinwheel, didn't even get an error message.

When I noticed not a single file of my project was changed when it stopped working I assumed a cache error somewhere, so in the end I 'fixed' it by restarting my computer (restarting XCode wasn't enough).

The joys of a .0 XCode version